# How to swap up/down buttons in NumericUpDown control of MahApps.Metro?

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I am currently using the MahApps.Metro NumericUpDown control to change frames in an image stack. The user feedback I have got from this is that the buttons feel the wrong way round, intuitively the button on the left would move back a frame and the button on the right would move forward. As such I would like to swap the order of the buttons

I have looked through the properties that the control has but I have been unable to find any that would allow me to change the order of the buttons.

Is there a way to do this without having to roll my own control?

Basically I would like to change from this:

[image: Standard numeric up down]

To this:

[image: Modified numeric up down]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

With latest MahApps version (v2.x) there is the new `SwitchUpDownButtons` property available to swap / switch the buttons.

**Older MahApps Versions**

There is no property where you can change the sequence of the up and down buttons. But you can take the original style which is available at the GitHub repository of MahApps.Metro and change the Template.

```
<Style x:Key="CustomNumericUpDownStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:NumericUpDown}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Controls:NumericUpDown}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Controls:NumericUpDown}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                    <Border x:Name="Base"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Controls:ControlsHelper.CornerRadius}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="PART_TextBoxColumn" Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="PART_ButtonsColumn" Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    MinWidth="20"
                                    MinHeight="0"
                                    Margin="0 0 -2 0"
                                    Padding="0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                    Controls:ControlsHelper.DisabledVisualElementVisibility="Collapsed"
                                    Controls:TextBoxHelper.ButtonContent="{TemplateBinding Controls:TextBoxHelper.ButtonContent}"
                                    Controls:TextBoxHelper.ButtonContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding Controls:TextBoxHelper.ButtonContentTemplate}"
                                    Controls:TextBoxHelper.ButtonFontFamily="{TemplateBinding Controls:TextBoxHelper.ButtonFontFamily}"
                                    Controls:TextBoxHelper.ButtonFontSize="{TemplateBinding Controls:TextBoxHelper.ButtonFontSize}"
                                    Controls:TextBoxHelper.ButtonWidth="{TemplateBinding Controls:TextBoxHelper.ButtonWidth}"
                                    Controls:TextBoxHelper.ButtonsAlignment="{TemplateBinding ButtonsAlignment}"
                                    Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="{TemplateBinding Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton}"
                                    Controls:TextBoxHelper.HasText="{TemplateBinding Controls:TextBoxHelper.HasText}"
                                    Controls:TextBoxHelper.SelectAllOnFocus="{TemplateBinding Controls:TextBoxHelper.SelectAllOnFocus}"
                                    Controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="{TemplateBinding Controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark}"
                                    Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="{TemplateBinding Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark}"
                                    Controls:TextBoxHelper.WatermarkAlignment="{TemplateBinding Controls:TextBoxHelper.WatermarkAlignment}"
                                    Controls:TextBoxHelper.WatermarkTrimming="{TemplateBinding Controls:TextBoxHelper.WatermarkTrimming}"
                                    Background="{x:Null}"
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                                    Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}"
                                    FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                    FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                    IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"
                                    IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                    TabIndex="{TemplateBinding TabIndex}"
                                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                        <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Buttons"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Padding, Converter={StaticResource ThicknessBindingConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static Converters:ThicknessSideType.Left}}"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <!-- down is now the first button -->
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_NumericDown"
                                            Width="{TemplateBinding UpDownButtonsWidth}"
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                            Delay="{TemplateBinding Delay}"
                                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                            IsTabStop="False"
                                            Style="{DynamicResource ChromelessButtonStyle}">
                                <Path x:Name="PolygonDown"
                                        Width="14"
                                        Height="3"
                                        Data="F1 M 19,38L 57,38L 57,44L 19,44L 19,38 Z "
                                        Fill="{DynamicResource GrayBrush1}"
                                        Stretch="Fill" />
                            </RepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_NumericUp"
                                            Width="{TemplateBinding UpDownButtonsWidth}"
                                            Delay="{TemplateBinding Delay}"
                                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                            IsTabStop="False"
                                            Style="{DynamicResource ChromelessButtonStyle}">
                                <Path x:Name="PolygonUp"
                                        Width="14"
                                        Height="14"
                                        Data="F1 M 35,19L 41,19L 41,35L 57,35L 57,41L 41,41L 41,57L 35,57L 35,41L 19,41L 19,35L 35,35L 35,19 Z "
                                        Fill="{DynamicResource GrayBrush1}"
                                        Stretch="Fill" />
                            </RepeatButton>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement"
                            Background="{DynamicResource ControlsDisabledBrush}"
                            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ControlsDisabledBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Controls:ControlsHelper.CornerRadius}"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Opacity="0"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                            Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(Controls:ControlsHelper.DisabledVisualElementVisibility), Mode=OneWay}" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ButtonsAlignment" Value="Left">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Buttons" Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Buttons" Property="Margin" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Padding, Converter={StaticResource ThicknessBindingConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static Converters:ThicknessSideType.Right}}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_ButtonsColumn" Property="Width" Value="*" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_TextBox" Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_TextBox" Property="Margin" Value="-2 0 0 0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_TextBox" Property="Margin" Value="-2 0 0 0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_TextBoxColumn" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Property="Opacity" Value="0.6" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="InterceptArrowKeys" Value="False" />
                        <Setter Property="InterceptManualEnter" Value="False" />
                        <Setter Property="InterceptMouseWheel" Value="False" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_NumericDown" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_NumericUp" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="InterceptManualEnter" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_TextBox" Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="PART_NumericUp" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_NumericUp" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush8}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PolygonUp" Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="PART_NumericUp" Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_NumericUp" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PolygonUp" Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="PART_NumericDown" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_NumericDown" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush8}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PolygonDown" Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="PART_NumericDown" Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_NumericDown" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PolygonDown" Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Base" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(Controls:ControlsHelper.MouseOverBorderBrush)}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="PART_TextBox" Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Base" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(Controls:ControlsHelper.FocusBorderBrush)}" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="HideUpDownButtons" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Buttons" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: It required me to update to the latest version of MahApps.Metro, but other than that, this worked straight out of the box. Exactly what I was looking for.